# Pairing for the native code compilation with Windows 7 on MacBookPro (using BootCamp for Xamarin Development)

Tags: macos, xamarin, windows-7

I am running Windows 7 on MacBookPro using BootCamp for Xamarin Development.

So, if I setup my MacBookPro like this and create a Xamarin project in Visual Studio 2015, is it possible to perform the pairing for the native code compilation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, because with BootCamp your MacBook runs Windows 7. You can develop your apps but you can not execute any iOS app if you do not have a second Mac somewhere else.

What you can do instead is to install Windows in a virtual machine with tools like Paralells or VirtualBox and connect it with your MacBook. This way you only need a single Mac if you want to develop an iOS app and using Visual Studio.

Comment: Yea ... kinda have a feeling Win 7 with BootCamp won't work. But, even the performance for MacBookPro is quite decent on it's own. Running a VM on non-Xeon machine usually really slow and problemetic, isn't it ? So .... the setup should be MacBookPro with Xamarin studio (without VS2015) and another window machine for the WebApI and database part I guess

Comment: It depents on your MacBook model you have. My MBP is from late 2014 and it works quite well. Even so I ditched Windows and moved completely to Xamarin Studio on my Mac.

Comment: Not me, I still need the window for VS WebApi and CouchDb 
Oh ... mind if i ask a bit more ? So i read about the Paralells desktop and it does look really cool. But i'm wondering if the Standard version of Paralells desktop enough for setting up the Xamarin dev environment ?

Comment: No I don't mind. I do not use Paralells. If you just want to try the combination of Windows in a virtual machine and Xamarin development on a Mac you could give VirtualBox a try. It works basically like any other virtualizing software.